# How to find XPath for button within iframe using python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have the following html object inside an iframe:

[html code for 'SUBMIT' button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe3rZ.png)

I need to find it's XPath in order to click on the "SUBMIT" button but cannot find it. XPath helper only shows "//iframe".

So far, I've tried:

```
submit = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='btnSubmit']")
submit.click
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All content, which is inside a `frame` or `iframe` cannot be accesed without switching to `iframe/frame`. So firstly switch to `frame` content:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name("frame_name"))
```

or

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//xpath/to/frame"))
```

Then you can locate your submit button and click on it:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='btnSubmit']"))).click()
```

Than switch to default content like this:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

**Note:** you have to add some imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```