# Switching to an iframe on android native and web app using appium via ROBOT framework

Tags: android, iframe, appium, robotframework

Hi I have been searching a lot on the internet to find how i am supposed to switch from web or native context view to an iframe. I am trying to automate a user logging into an app and the third piece of identification is generating a OTP. This happens to be inside an iframe and i have tried quite a few things to interact with it. Firstly I cannot find any good documentation on how to achieve this through keywords (Appium) using robot, and i do not have a lot of programming experience to write it in python then call it but i have tried.

First thing i tried was using the keyword 'switch to context' and 'get contexts' which i am already using to switch between native and webview already:

```
List Contexts
${contexts}=                              Get Contexts
${native}=                                Get From List           ${contexts}           0
${webview}=                               Get From List           ${contexts}           1  #-1
${chromeviewiframe}                       get from list           ${contexts}           -1  #1
Set Test Variable                         ${native}
Set Test Variable                         ${webview}
set test variable                         ${chromeviewiframe}

#Test Case code
sleep 60 
list contexts
switch to context  ${chromeviewiframe}
wait until element is visible  xpath=//*[@id="btnSMS"]  30
click element  xpath=//*[@id="btnSMS"]
```

However it never finds the iframe or button and therefore times out - I am not sure if 'get contexts' can be used to find iframes.

I have also tried to put the little bit of code appium supplied on their page into a python file in which i intended to call and hoped that would switch frames but didnt succeed at this attempt

```
#no idea what library's i am supposed to import and if the return makes sense?
class _frames():
def frame (self):
self.driver.switch_to.frame(3)
return   self.driver.switch_to.frame(3)
```

My iframe xpath is (x'd out some characters) `#iframe   //*[@id="xxx2iframe"]`

I have been having errors such as:
[image]

The phone is still activate and connection isnt lost but i think it just cant find the iframe context - I cant properly test the python file as the code isn't compelete and im not sure what i need to do to fix it to test that 'solution' out. I also wondered if i had another file calling selenium and call the switch frame keyword would it work for appium automation as they use the same drivers? I assume not?

Help to figure this out would be much appreciated, there isn't much point in me writing automation test cases if i cannot get it to automatically log in and get past this point.

Kind Regards, Jem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so if anyone else searches for this question ive came up with an answer which is similar to the solution to this question: [How to find XPath for button within iframe using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243809/how-to-find-xpath-for-button-within-iframe-using-python)

However it didn't relate and explain how it could be used in Robot framework so what i did was:

1. Clicked (ctrl+click) on appium keywords from my robot file which open the '_applicationmannagement.py' file which contains all the python methods which make up the keywords for appium Library

2.Inserted the following method in python:

```
def frame (self):
  driver = self._current_application()
  driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath( "//*[@id=\"xxx2iframe\"]"))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(("xpath","//* 
  [@id='btnSMS']"))).click()
```

3. Then in my robot file i simply just call the python method frame by writing the word 'frame' as part of my test case

This method switches to the iframe by using xpath and  then it waits up until 30 seconds to find the button and once found it clicks it.

One thing to point out which was stopping this was the emulator might need to be restarted  as at one point it would not load the iframe on the device.

I really hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Please set your default browser as Chrome and then restart the device. The webviews will be automatically detected by Appium after that.

Comment: Hi i thanks for the input but i needed code to actually switch to the iframe view restarting the device and making default to chrome would not have helped.